# How do I test a class method using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following basic setup named `Main.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()

    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

if __name__=="__main__":
    Main().run()
```

I'm using Pycharm and I have created another file named `test.py` and imported `Main.py` but when I run Pytest from the terminal (in Pycharm) it's not finding any tests. My test file is basically this:

```
import Main

def test_add():
    assert add(2, 4) == 6

main = Main.Main()
```

How can I run tests on methods using this setup?

Comment: Can you share the command you're using to run the test?

Answer (score 1):

First, your file should be named `test.py`, not `Test.py`.  Files in Python are usually not named with upper-case letters.

Second, you defined an "add" method, but it has no self parameter, so I'm not sure how you meant to call it.

Third, you haven't referenced it in your test file in a way that will work.  Perhaps you mean `Main.add(2, 4)` ?

Comment: Test.py was a typo, and there was a self parameter in the actualy code. I've updated it here now.

Comment: Pytest should at least find your test_add test and run it, producing a NameError. Something else is not right in your setup.